# How to add margins in Swift

Tags: ios, swift2

I seem unable to add any margins to my `UILabel` and wrapping it inside of a stack view does not help either. Best I can tell the `.layoutMargins` line is being completely ignored...

```
let helloLabel:UILabel = UILabel()
helloLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
helloLabel.text = "Hello, World!"
helloLabel.textAlignment = .Center
helloLabel.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(25,80,20,10)
stack.addArragnedSubView(helloLabel)
```

Comment: You do realize that the margins are between the view you set them on and *its* contents? Maybe you should set the margin on the stack view instead?

Comment: Setting the margin on the stack view also has no impact...

Comment: What is a label margin, in your mind? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Simpy trying to place a margin between the UILabel and the other UI elements

Comment: You mean you want to put the label at a distance from other elements? Then just put it at a distance from them. That's totally up to you; no special "margins" are needed for that.

Comment: How would you place them a distance apart? Everything in the view is stacked with a margin of zero

Comment: You can improve the title of your question. Add margins to _what_? Why does it matter that it is Swift?

Comment: "Everything in the view is stacked with a margin of zero" Please try to describe the problem in words that are meaningful. In _what_ view? What does "stacked" mean here?

Comment: Simply trying to add margins to any UI element. My sample shows a UILabel, but presumably it would be the same for any type of view. And the language certainly does matter. I am trying to write an app in Swift, an answer in python is not going to help any...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently this is impossible to do. However you can get close if you are ok with the top and bottom margins being the same...

```
let helloLabel:UILabel = UILabel()
helloLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
helloLabel.text = "Hello, World!"
helloLabel.textAlignment = .Center
stack.addArragnedSubView(helloLabel)

NSLayoutConstraint(item:stack, attribute:.Width, relatedBy:.Equal, toItem:self.view, attribute:.Width, multiplier:1, constant:0).active = true
//top margin
stack.spacing = 25
//left margin
NSLayoutConstraint(item:helloLabel, attribute:.Leading, relatedBy:.Equal, toItem:stack, attribute:.Leading, multiplier:1, constant:80).active = true
//right margin
NSLayoutConstraint(item:helloLabel, attribute:.Trailing, relatedBy:.Equal, toItem:stack, attribute:.Trailing, multiplier:1, constant:-10).active = true
```

Comment: This is totally wrong. You must not impose constraints between a stack view and one of its arranged subviews.

Comment: You have a better idea? I would rather have code that kindof works, then code that doesn't work at all...

Comment: Certainly I have a better idea; I've been placing interface elements at desired distances from other interface elements for years. If you would explain in meaningful and precise terms what it is that you want to do, I would be happy to advise you on how to do it.